# Can I build android executable right from my android application

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-widget, executable

How do I build a android executable from my android application? I am building an application where it would send some application data to another device. If the receiver is using my application, there is no problem. But if the receiver is not using my application or not aware of it, the application data means nothing to him, unless the sender informs him about it.

I wish to build a executable, right from my android application, which will run on receiver end. Receiver may not modify it but can run it easily.

#### Example of such use:

Video recorder or converter application which convert/record video on a custom format and play it. Now the sender wants to send that video to his friend. Unless he have installed such video, he can't access it. However if it is possible for the sender to create some executable to embed that video, which can run on any android device it would be great.

Comment: Do you look for a possibility to send your developed Android application to someone else?

Comment: No what I want is to compile android app in android itself..

Comment: Also after compiling I want to send the application to someone else..

Comment: @biztiger Theoretically this is possible (Android is Linux under the cover and Android development tools for Linux very much exist). Practically, I think that there is a long way there...

Comment: possible duplicate of [porting javac and dx to android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688736/porting-javac-and-dx-to-android)

Comment: Is there any alternate solution for this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if it were possible, it is definitely not practical to compile an application on an Android device.  Why not make the compiled application available in the Android market and/or your own URL, and then get the receiver to download and install it?

Comment: But how the receiver will know, which application to download for opening that file. I don't expect sender will call or message the receiver about it. Can you suggest a alternative way.

Comment: How are you sending the data to the receiver? Since you don't know if the receiver has your app or not, then it must be through a standard method like email, sms, or an instant message.  You can use that same mechanism to tell the receiver that they need your app in order to view the data and provide a link to it.

Answer (score 0):

Like Elevine said, you should send a URL to App in Market instead of sending an app.

If google/Android evev allow sending app directly, Spammers, virus writers will love the "features".     It is as bad as ActiveX plugin date of IE5,6.

BTW, I thought about this kind of approach before.  One can have all the prebuilt jar, dex files ready and just want to zip them together with new data as resources, signed it with the right key.  It is possible to do it in the phone.  But you really don't want to do put your signing key in anyone's phone.

It is much better/simpler to just submit the needed data to a server in the cloud have sign the package there.

Comment: The application will be available to official android market and some third party android market too. But, the sender should not be bother if the receiver have installed the app, or not. Like in the example stated above, sender will normally send the video file like any other video file format. Now receiver don't have that application installed he can't play that file and possibly delete that file. The chance of the receiver searching android market or internet for playing/opening such file is very low. What would you suggest in that case..